# When a table view is dragged down, how to set the color of the view behind it?

Tags: ios

I have a green navigation bar and a green table view header that together look like this:

[image]

But when the user scrolls the table view down it appears like this:

[image]

I'm attempting to set the color of the grey portion that is revealed when the user drags down to also be green, but can't work out how to do so.

If I set the tableview's background color to green this does not affect it, setting that to green sets the view behind the grey strip but does not affect that strip itself:

[image]

Here is the grey strip in the view hierarcy:

[image]

Is there some way I can set it to green, so when the user drags down they don't see they gray beneath?

The table view in the storyboard is like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting the table view's `backgroundColor`?

Comment: The large green view on the left of the view hieararcy diagram is the result of setting the table view's backgroundColor.

Comment: Could you show us the list of the views in you storyboard.

Comment: Done however it is just a regular table view controller, its actually the XCode master-detail template project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same problem, I solved it with this code.

```
    CGRect frame = self.ContactTable.bounds;
    frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
    UIView* bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
    bgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    // Adding the view 
    [self.tableView insertSubview:bgView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `backgroundView` property of `UITableView`:

```
let backgroundView = UIView()
backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
```

It will automatically resize to the size of the table view.

Comment: Thanks, that works however it also makes the bottom of the table green if there are only a small number of table rows. It doesn't target specifically the view at the top, which is what I was hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Dobiho's answer in **Swift**:

```
var frame = tableView.bounds
frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height
let bgView = UIView(frame: frame)
bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
bgView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth

tableView.addSubview(bgView)
```

Comment: qq - this solves over scroll at the top when you drag down, but not at the foot when you drag up. I tried replicating it but using  `frame.origin.y = frame.size.height` but that doesn't work - I'm sure it's an easy fix but what is it?